# Why Surefire plugin is need in Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have used Maven for a while. In my previous projects, i did not create pom.xml from scratch, and I've seen Surefire plugin always already added to POM.

At first I thought Surefire is a must for Maven to be able to search for test java files to run, however even after I remove Surefire plugin from POM, Maven is still able to find the test cases under src/test/java.

So is the purpose of Surefire to add additional features such as in:

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

but not absolutely necessary to run "mvn test"?

Thanks

Comment: The point is if you don't write maven-surefire-plugin in your pom you always inherit from the super pom which contains by default a [definition for maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging) and yes maven-surefire-plugin is necessary for running unit tests...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very first line you [doc](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/) you provided says:

> ". It generates reports in two different file formats:"

And reports are very important, I assume you must have seen reports after running test to check coverage and other stats.

You have answer somewhere in your question itself :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for reasons why so many plugins required such as Sure-fire and fail-safe..

found that we need **surefire** for "test" phase to execute the **UNIT TEST** of an application
which is the least minimal activity we do to after compiling our code therefore surefire is omnipresent.